# How to obtain a list of zoneIds for which their day start is within past 5 minutes?

Tags: java, timezone

Say the server timestamp right now is 2022-01-26 16:02:00 PDT, I want to return list of timezones that have just passed the midnight (day start), in this case, 16:02 PDT is 2 minutes past 00:00 UTC, so return [UTC] in this case. How do I return a list of zoneIds (from this set: `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`) for a given timestamp T?

Comment: This Question could use some rewriting for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“PDT” is not a [real time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). I assume you meant `America/Los_Angeles`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) ;
```

Define your desired moment as a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2022-01-26" ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "16:02" ) ;
ZonedDateTime target = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
```

Get your set of time zone names by calling [`ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html#getAvailableZoneIds()).

```
Set< String > names = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds() ;
```

Loop those zone names. Obtain a `ZoneId` object for each. Use that zone object to adjust our target into that zone. Then determine the first moment of the day in that zone on that date.

Your Question makes the mistake of assuming the day starts at 00:00. Not true. Some dates in some zones start at another time such as 01:00. Let *java.time* determine the first moment of the day with a call to `LocalDate#atStartOfDay`.

```
Duration limit = Duration.ofMinutes( 5 ) ;
List< ZoneId > hits = new ArrayList <>( names.size() ) ;
for( String name : names ) 
{
    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( name ) ;
    ZonedDateTime zdt = target.withZoneSameInstant( ZoneId ) ;
    ZonedDateTime startOfDay = zdt.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay( zoneId ); 
    Duration d = Duration.between ( startOfDay , zdt ) ;
    if( d.compareTo( limit ) <= 0 ) { hits.add( zoneId ) ; }
}
return List.of( hits ) ;
```

All of this code is rough draft, untested.

Comment: zdt.toLocalDate().atZone( zoneId ). `atZone` does not seem to be a valid function? but i get what you mean. i used something like this `nowZoned.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay(nowZoned.getZone()).toInstant()`.

Comment: @return0 Yes, I intended `atStartOfDay`. Fixed, thanks.